# what is bad in this table schema structure

Tags: sqlite, database-design, database-schema

I have got a table structure which is as follows:

```
`CREATE TABLE "pages" (
   "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
   "title" varchar(255),
   "body" varchar(255),
   "author" varchar(255), 
   "email" varchar(255), 
   "reference" varchar(255),
   "created_at" datetime,
   "updated_at" datetime);`
```

Is this table structure bad?

## edit-1

Its sqlite database i am using.

Comment: "Is this table structure bad?"  It's difficult to tell if you don't format the question nicely.  Please properly format the table definition so that it's readable.

Comment: Did someone tell you it was bad? We'd need more context...because I don't see anything blatantly wrong with it.

Comment: I have no idea if it's bad. All we can do at the moment is guess what each of those columns is used for, which isn't really a good basis to give feedback from.

Comment: well...yes..i got a comment from the tech lead that it is bad its not properly structured he said. Do i need to change the sizes of varchar?

Comment: I don't know your requirements, but I think its good to use `IDENTITY(1,1)` instead of `AUTOINCREMENT` and avoid naming column as `reference` which is a keyword in `SQL Server`, it can cause problems while writing queries. Set the default value for created_at on insert. For eg: `DEFAULT GETDATE()`. Examples are in `SQL SERVER` syntax. Regards

Comment: "I got a comment from the tech lead that it is bad its not properly structured"  Why don't you ask this tech lead what they meant?  We can only guess.  It's quite silly to ask random strangers to guess what someone else meant.  Ask them, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the limited info that you have provided. If the table fits your needs then no it is not bad.

However if you will have the same author with multiple entries. You might want to consider removing the author from your pages table and have a separate table for authors then use a foreign key relationship between authors and pages.

You could do the same thing with the email if you will have multiple emails for each author.

Answer (score 0):

If its failing it might be due to the space between "v" and "archar" on the 2nd line? Although that might just be a cut/paste error.

Comment: hm, not sure why that was downvoted - it was a perfectly sane response to what was visible at the time..

Comment: Sure, but the question was about table structure, not syntax.  This would have made a good comment, but it is not an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us much to go on. But if your project has a technical lead who expects you to meet certain structural standards, there should be a book, paper, file, or web page that tells you what's expected of you.

The only column that's not nullable is the meaningless id number. That's almost certainly a problem. I don't know what all the column names mean, but I doubt that any of them should be nullable.

All the varchar() columns are the same length. That's probably not what you want.

I'm going to guess that "pages" refers to web pages. If that's the case, you *probably* want "title" to be unique.  (And you *probably* want it to be less than 255 characters.)

If "email" means the current email address of "author", then there's a transitive dependency between "author" and "email". (It's not yet in 3NF.) If "email" means the email address of  "author" at the time of publication, there's probably a multi-valued dependency between "author" and "email". (So it's not yet in 4NF.)

You *probaby* don't want the email address to allow 255 characters either.

The columns "created_at" and "updated_at" are about the row, not about the "page". I prefer to keep data about the row in a separate table; that will reduce the size of the real data, narrow the table, allow more rows per page, and increase speed.