# partial form for nested models in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two models pages and author, here is the code of model pages:

## edit -1

now my models are as follows:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :title, :presence => true

belongs_to :author


end
```

author model:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :pages
end
```

and my form is as follows:

```
 <%= form_for(@page) do |f| %>
  <% if @page.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@page.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @page.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
   <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
   <p>
   <%= f.fields_for :author do |fields| %>
         <%= f.label :author %><br />
         <%= fields.text_field :author %>
   <% end %>
   </p>
   <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
   <p>
    <%= f.label :reference %><br />
    <%= f.select(:reference,[['google',1],['yahoo',2],['MSN',3],['Ask',4]]) %>
  </p>
   <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

and controller :

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    
  def index
    @total = Page.count
    @pages = Page.find(:all)
  end
  
  def show
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end
  
  def new
    @page = Page.new
    
    
  end
  
  def create
    @page = Page.new(params[:page])
    if @page.save
        redirect_to pages_path, :notice => "The data has been saved!"
    else
        render "new"
    end
  end 
    
  def edit
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    
    
  end
    
  def update
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    
        if @page.update_attributes(params[:page])
            redirect_to pages_path, :notice => "Your post has been updated!"
        else
            render "edit"
        end 
        
  end 
  
  def destroy
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    @page.destroy
    redirect_to pages_path, :notice => "Your page has been deleted!"
  end
end
```

Now when i am submitting the form it is giving me this error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in PagesController#create

Author(#40328004) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#32291496)
Rails.root: C:/rorapp

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:19:in `new'
app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:19:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"hzBlXsdUjEDDCLp036R8bJBwep6BdATSvJPNwt0M8Dg=",
 "page"=>{"title"=>"",
 "body"=>"",
 "author"=>{"author"=>""},
 "email"=>"",
 "reference"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Submit"}
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

and one more problem if I add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :author` to my Page model, then the field is not displayed at all. I really want to accomplish this.. any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this doesn't work in reverse with the association.  I'm sorry for the mistake.  You could do the following, but then your pages controller is acting on the author, which isn't really appropriate.  You could make an author controller though, and include fields_for :pages, to have the author and the first page created at the same time.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @author = Author.new
    @page = @author.pages.new
  end


  def create
    @author = Author.create(params[:author])
  end
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pages
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end

<%= form_for(@author, :url => pages_url) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :author %>
    <%= f.fields_for :pages do |fields| %>
        <%= fields.text_area :body %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: author field is a string type to take input of author name from the user through a text field. I will try your solution and get back to give the feedback :) thanks

Comment: I have edited my question with latest changes and problems..would appreciate if you could guide me on it.

Comment: So is the field name "name"? <%= fields.text_field :author %> is a problem.  The text field isn't author, author refers to the object.  I don't know what your schema looks like, but if the author's name field is "name" you would do <%= fields.text_field :name %>.

The reason it wasn't showing up with accepts_nested_attributes_for is because you need to specify a field on the author database.

Comment: field name is author... and thats what I have put in the textfield as well. but i am getting the error now..i have updated and edited my question.

Comment: I've updated my answer as well.  If author doesn't exist yet you'll need to build that too.  See the end of my answer.

As an aside, I think if it refers to the author's name, you should change the name of the field to "name".  author.author isn't very descriptive.

Comment: i am still getting typemismatch error.. `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in PagesController#create

Author(#34126524) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#32291496)
Rails.root: C:/rorapp`

Comment: no..but just tried it now..when i am putting it..the field for author fieldname is not getting displayed at all.

Comment: ok.. now I accessed the fiel author using this.. `<p>
   
   <%= f.label :author %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :author %>
   
   </p>`  but now I am getting this error : `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in PagesController#create

Author(#35072532) expected, got String(#19322052)
Rails.root: C:/rorapp`

Comment: @mad_programmer I'm sorry, I kinda messed up here.  I didn't realize you couldn't use accepts_nested_attributes_for in reverse.  See my new edit.