# Rails Association Help for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Can i get some suggestions on building association models to my app.

I basically have a Project model which will hold the various models:

```
one client
many partners
1 accounts
```

would i just do an association with each of those models to the Project or should it be some kind of 'association through'

Comment: i haven't tried much just need some tips on how to do the associations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest go through the association basics and then add some code for use to help you out.

There is ample of information available.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-models.htm

http://railscasts.com/episodes/3-find-through-association

http://www.slideshare.net/JamesEdwardGrayII/associations-in-rails

[ruby on rails associations newbie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249685/ruby-on-rails-associations-newbie)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Hashhh that should be enough... :D

Go through the basics and whatever you dont understand we are here to help you :)