# Linking two views in Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi I am new to ruby on rails.

I have two tables which is `Lov_names` and `lov_values`.

My Lov names table is as follows:-

```
 id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  description character varying(255),
  deleted integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT lov_names_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

My Lov values table is as follows:-

```
 id serial NOT NULL,
  lov_name_id integer,
  lov_value character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  sequence integer,
  deleted integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT lov_values_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

As you can see from above lov value has a reference to the lov name

I have created views for them using scaffolding.

The view for lov name is:-

```
<% @lov_names.each do |c| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to c.id, {:action => 'show', :id => c.id} %> &nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= c.name %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= c.description %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', {:action => 'edit', :id => c.id} %> &nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', {:action => 'delete', :id => c.id},
    :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this value?" } %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

The view for lov value is as follows:-

```
<% @lov_values.each do |c| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to c.id, {:action => 'show', :id => c.id} %> &nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= c.lov_name_id %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= c.lov_value %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= c.sequence %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', {:action => 'edit', :id => c.id} %> &nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', {:action => 'delete', :id => c.id},
    :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this value?" } %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Now the problem I am facing is that I want to link the two view that is when I click on id in `Lov names` I should be able to generate the corresponding `lov value for that id`. Also I should be able to add, edit and delete the `Lov values` in that page from the view which I have created.

can someone please guide me on this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the association between two tables and by that way you can easily access the record of another and do whatever modification you required.

For example, if lov_value belongs_to lov_name table means, you should have the foreign_key of lov_name in the lov_value table.

Have a look at this documentation of how to create associations.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Also, have a look at this thread.

[ruby on rails associations newbie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249685/ruby-on-rails-associations-newbie)

Once you get the idea, then you can easily access the lov_value by clicking the lov_name_id.

Make the other view as a partial so that, you can reuse the views

Hope it helps.